# Weird Behaviour of JSCH

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I am trying to execute multiple commands via SSH using JSCH library.I am facing a strange issue.When I try to run the program in eclipse the code completes the execution but the command(mkdir test) is not executed in the server.But when I debug step by step the command gets executed and the folder gets created.Can anyone explain what am I doing wrong here? The code is as below:

```
public static void runCommand() throws JSchException, IOException{
  JSch jsch=new JSch();

  Session session=jsch.getSession("user","linuxip",22);
 List<String>commandList=new ArrayList<String>();
          commandList.add("cd deploy");
          commandList.add("mkdir test");

    session.setPassword(password);
    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.connect();
    session.setTimeout(500);
    System.out.println("Connecting..");
  Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
  OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();

  ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("sudo su - wsp ");

  System.out.println("connected..");
 // channel.setInputStream(null);

  ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
 // InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
  ((ChannelExec) channel).setPty(true);
  channel.connect();
  channel.setOutputStream(System.out);
    for(String command:commandList) {

        out.write((command+"\n").getBytes());


    }

  out.write(("exit"+"\n").getBytes());
 out.flush();    

 out.close();

 channel.disconnect();
 session.disconnect();



}}
```

Comment: I wonder if you `close` before and disconnect before the commands finish executing. Try adding a sleep before `out.close` to test this hypothesis. If this works, then you should change your code to read the exit code from each command. See http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html for how to read the exit code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution.I was doing a silly mistake of setting the session timeout to 500,which was very less as the command took more time to execute.So changed it to a higher value.
session.setTimeout(50000);